# "SyntaxError: can't assign to literal" error with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I'm trying to run some code that my professor gave me that is supposed to find an item in a list, and count the number of occurrences. I get an error that says "SyntaxError: can't assign to literal" when I try and run it though. Here is the code:

```
def function(list_of_coins):
    count=0
    for i in list_of_coins:
        if(i == 'Dime'):
            count = count+1
    return(count)


list_of_coins = ["Penny","Dime","Dime","Nickel","Dime","Penny","Dime"]

print("count: ",function(list_of_coins))


non_dime_list = [1 for 1 in list_of_coins if 1!="Dime"]
print(non_dime_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a error here `[1 for 1 in list_of_coins if 1!="Dime"]`

It should be  `[i for i in list_of_coins if i!="Dime"]`

Answer (score 0):

Where you say

```
non_dime_list = [1 for 1 in list_of_coins if 1!="Dime"]
```

you are treating 1 like a variable, but variables cannot start with numbers. You have to replace it with

```
non_dime_list = [i for i in list_of_coins if i!="Dime"]
```

I would also suggest to rewrite your code a little to have a relevant function name and remove redundant parenthesis.

```
def count_dimes(lst):
    count = 0
    for i in lst:
        if i == 'Dime':
            count += 1
    return count


list_of_coins = ["Penny", "Dime", "Dime", "Nickel", "Dime", "Penny", "Dime"]
print("count: ", count_dimes(list_of_coins))
non_dime_list = [i for i in list_of_coins if i != "Dime"]
print(non_dime_list)
```